# How do I make limits on where a character can move in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

So in my coding class, my project partner and I are trying to make a game where you move a character around using wasd through a maze. Its a top-down type view. (side note, we are making the make where the background is the entire maze, and we just move the background around when the character gets to the side of the screen. There are multiple walls on the screen, however.) So I figured out how to make the character stop moving and the background start moving (until needed stop location) when the character gets to the edge of the screen, but when they press the key to move again the character goes off the screen. I know I could fix this with a boarder where the character cant leave, but I don't know how to keep the character from being able to go though the walls, based on the fact that all the walls are just lines on the background image. I can make the character stop moving when they get to the wall, but once the character stops moving, if the user presses the key to go towards the wall again they can walk though.

(side note, all characters, and the background image move using variables such as x_position and y-position and x_change and y_change)
I thought about making the code where it stops the character into something like
if main_char_x >= (x position of background image based on position parameters) 
rather than == or some sort of while loop but I think that will result in the character slowly inching forwards.

I would post examples of our code, but our maze/background is not complete yet so I do not know where the boarders would be at exactly, or the position of the background image at all. AKA I don't have examples, because we haven't actually coded this part of the program yet, and I'm planning how to code it.

```
    if (background_x <= (certain point) and background_x >= (certain point)) and (background_y >= (certain position) and background_y <= (certain position)):
        if main_char_x == (wall position):
            main_char_x_change = 0
```

^^^ quick example of my thought process

If I need to clarify anything please just ask.

We are using pygame and PyCharm Edu 3.5

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reset the position to before the line, everytime it crosses the line, before rendering. Something like this:

```
if char_x >= background_line_x:
   char_x = background_line_x - 1
```

Repeat for all 4 boundaries and you're set